# Angular, Disable submit button using [disabled] to check form validity

Tags: html, angular, typescript, form-control

I'm trying to disable a submit button using `[disable]=form.controls[...].invalid` condition checking. The submit button should be disabled if there is an input fields is empty or `invalid`. But looks like i'm doing it wrong. The button is disabled when i fill some fields and left some fields empty, except for the first input field . When i filled the first input field, the button become enabled (while the other input fields are still empty or `invalid`).

```js
//component.ts
form01: FormGroup;
public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
  dateFormat: 'dd-mmm-yyyy',
};

setDate(): void {
  let date = new Date();
  this.form01.patchValue({
    DoB: {
      date: {
        year: date.getFullYear(),
        month: date.getMonth() + 1,
        day: date.getDate()
      }
    }
  });
}

clearDate(): void {
  this.form01.patchValue({
    DoB: null
  });
}

constructor(public builder: FormBuilder) {
  this.form01 = this.builder.group({
    email: [null, Validators.required], //text
    DoB: [null, Validators.required], //radio button
    gender: [null, Validators.required], //date picker
  });
}

results: object = new Object();
functionForm01() {
  this.results = [{
    {
      "email": this.form01.controls.email.value
    },
    {
      "DoB": this.form01.controls.DoB.value
    },
    {
      "gender": this.form01.controls.gender.value
    }
  }]
  console.log(this.result);

  this.form01.reset();
}
```

```html
<!--component.html-->
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="form01">
    email:<input type="text" name="email" formControlName="email" required/> gender:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" formControlName="gender" value="male"> male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" formControlName="gender" value="female"> female<br> DoB:
    <my-date-picker name="DoB" [options]="myDatePickerOptions" formControlName="DoB" required></my-date-picker>

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="form01.controls['email' || 'DoB' || 'gender'].invalid" (click)="functionForm01()">Click</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm using Angular typescript and `myDatePicker` package from [this link](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker). Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can enable/disable the button by checking the validity of your form:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!disableBtn">Click</button>
```

Inside your component:

```
let disableBtn = false;
this. form01.valueChanges 
            .subscribe((changedObj: any) => {
                 this.disableBtn = this. form01.valid;
            });
```

Or via HTML:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!form01.valid" (click)="functionForm01()">Click</button>
```

Comment: property `valid` doesn't exist on type `()=> void`

Comment: FormGroup has that property ??  I using the valid & dirty check to show a save bar and enable/disable the save/cancel button.

can you provide a plunkr or https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Answer (score 15):

Since you have your formGroup object, you can disable the button if form01 is not valid

```
<!--component.html-->
    <div>
      <form [formGroup]="form01">
        email:<input type="text" name="email" formControlName="email" required/> gender:
        <input type="radio" name="gender" formControlName="gender" value="male"> male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" formControlName="gender" value="female"> female<br> DoB:
        <my-date-picker name="DoB" [options]="myDatePickerOptions" formControlName="DoB" required></my-date-picker>

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form01.valid" (click)="functionForm01()">Click</button>

      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: so we dont need to check one by one?

Comment: no, why you would like to check one by one? FormGroup will check for you one by one :)

Comment: moohkooh is right, form01 contains all the controls and form01 is invalid if any of its controls are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]=" form01.controls['email' ].invalid || form01.controls['DoB' ].invalid || form01.controls['gender' ].invalid " (click)="functionForm01()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to import FormsModule inside the app.module.ts under imports import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
     FormsModule      
])}
```